# Woocommerce Checkout scroll_to_notices

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like the scroll to click on the "check out" button, go to the top of the site, instead of just going to that part

[Checkout Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxTxB.png)

[Scroll to notices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2p5d.png)

I found this function in code in checkout.js

```
    submit_error: function( error_message ) {
        $( '.woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout, .woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message' ).remove();
        wc_checkout_form.$checkout_form.prepend( '<div class="woocommerce-NoticeGroup woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout">' + error_message + '</div>' ); // eslint-disable-line max-len
        wc_checkout_form.$checkout_form.removeClass( 'processing' ).unblock();
        wc_checkout_form.$checkout_form.find( '.input-text, select, input:checkbox' ).trigger( 'validate' ).blur();
        wc_checkout_form.scroll_to_notices();
        $( document.body ).trigger( 'checkout_error' );
    },
    scroll_to_notices: function() {
        var scrollElement           = $( '.woocommerce-NoticeGroup-updateOrderReview, .woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout' );

        if ( ! scrollElement.length ) {
            scrollElement = $( '.form.checkout' );
        }
        $.scroll_to_notices( scrollElement );
    }
};
```

But even if I delete the scroll_to_notice, it still scrolls to the same part

Comment: So what did you tried? We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Even if I change something in this code, it seems that it does not respond in the "checkout", I would like to know if I am in the correct location of woocommerce for this.

Comment: You can't change core files, it's something prohibited for multiple reasons. The code you are displaying is the right code, but maybe woocommerce takes a minified version. You can check all enqueued files in [`WC_Frontend_Scripts` class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php)